# Как сделать добавление товара в корзину!

Tags: jquery, ajax, битрикс

Есть у меня кнопка на ней ссылка которая передаёт значения!

```
?action=ADD2BASKET&amp;id=26049&amp;quantity=1
```

Еще есть скрипт который передаёт значения ссылки в файл.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btnBuyOPTPanel').each(function(i){
        $(this).click(function() {
            this.blur();
            var link = $(this).attr('href').match(/\?.*$/);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: '/ajax/add2basket.php'+link.valueOf(),
                success: function(data){

                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

итого у меня получается ссылка при клике такая

```
/ajax/add2basket.php?action=ADD2BASKET&amp;id=26049&amp;quantity=1
```

Дальше нужно обработать эту ссылку. Вот только как ?

Я понимаю это так, нужно получить эти параметры через get верно ?

Comment: Все верно, получаете гет параметры. А потом сохраняете их, например в сессии.

Comment: @zakiroof 
`<?require_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_before.php");?>

<?Bitrix\Main\Loader::includeModule("catalog");

$fields = [
    'PRODUCT_ID' => $_GET['id'], // ID товара
    'QUANTITY' => $_GET['quantity'], // количество
];
$r = Bitrix\Catalog\Product\Basket::addProduct($fields);
if (!$r->isSuccess()) {
    var_dump($r->getErrorMessages());
}?>` 

При обработке возвращается ошибка 500

Comment: В bitrix не разбираюсь. Но в любом случае смотри логи.